# Why an enum in an object instance has a static context?

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following class:

```
public class HandleResourceReferencesParams
{
    public Factory Factory { get; set; }
    public DataObject Resource { get; set; }
    public HandleAction Action { get; set; }

    public enum HandleAction
    {
        Activate,
        Disable,
        Terminate
    }
}
```

Which is used in the following code:

```
var parameters = new HandleResourceReferencesParams();
parameters.Factory = context.Factory;
parameters.Resource = resource;
parameters.Action = parameters.HandleAction.Terminate; // Does not compile
HandleResourceReferences(parameters);
```

By using `parameters.HandleAction`, I get a compile error:

> Cannot access static enum 'HandleAction' in non-static context

The enum is clearly not declared 'static'. Why does it have a static context when it is referenced from an object instance (non static as well)?

**EDIT:**
I already found the solution mentioned by Tim (Thanks by the way). I am just trying to understand why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is unfortunate, but it's not unfortunate that you can't *do* it... you're trying to access a member of a type, rather than a member of an *instance* of the type, but you're doing so "via" an instance.

Basically, it's the same reason that this code fails to compile:

```
Thread t = new Thread(...);
t.Start();
t.Sleep(1000); // Nope, Sleep is a static method
```

*All* nested types are effectively static members, in that you can't have a type which is specific to an instance of the containing type.

From the C# spec, section 10.3.7 (emphasis mine):

> When a field, method, property, event, operator or constructor declaration includes a `static` modifier, it declares a static member. **In addition, a constant or type declaration implicitly declares a static member.**

So the enum is a static member of the type, despite not having the `static` modifier.

Comment: It should also be noted that enums values are a set of named constants .

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
parameters.Action = HandleResourceReferencesParams.HandleAction.Terminate;
```

You assign an enum to the instance-property, but the enum itself is like a static variable.

So you cannot call an enum through an instance of the outer class in which it is declared. This is similar to the compiler error if you try to use a static field through an instance of it's class:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public static string Foo = "Foo";
    public string FooProp { get; set; }
}
```

You cannot access the static field `FooClass.Foo` via instance either:

```
var foo = new FooClass();
foo.FooProp = foo.Foo; // does not compile either, you have to use FooClass.Foo
```

An [`enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx)  consists of a set of named constants, [`const`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) is `static` implicitly.

Why does the compiler don't let me use an instance? Because it tries to prevent you from obvious careless mistakes. You don't need an instance so don't use it.

Comment: I found how to make it compile, I am asking for the reason why it is not compiling how I did it

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: `parameters.Action` is the instance property that you want to assign, but the enum itself is `HandleResourceReferencesParams.HandleAction.Terminate` which is not called through an instance of the outer class similar to a static field.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou: note that i've also edited my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

> I found how to make it compile, I am asking for the reason why it is not  compiling how I did it

HandleAction.Terminate is a value of an enum.
Its value is not linked with an instance of HandleResourceReferencesParams but its a type nested in the object HandleResourceReferencesParams.

It is the definition of an enum, not a member like a property or variable which would be instantiated.

The only specificity of a nested definition (enum, struct or class) is its specific privileges with its parent class.